# How to store numpy objects ( matrices ) fast?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, append

I have to store a list of **`numpy`** matrices. Two approaches I tried:

1.Create a **`list`** and append to it:

```
ls_ws=[]
for ind in range(iterations):
    ...
    ls_ws.append(ls_w) # ls_w is a matrix of size 6,1
```

**Problem:** Fast at start, gets very slow at end.

2.Create a matrix of zeros and modify it:

```
for ind in range(iterations):
    ...
    ls_ws=np.matrix(np.zeros((6,iterations)))
```

**Problem:** I am not very sure but this seems to the same speed irrespective of each iteration it is at.
Weird thing I get, if I set iterations to small number it is fast. But if I set it to large number like 1500 it is very slow for each iteration ( even the first iteration ).

---

The second approach should be fast, but is very slow if I set iterations to a large number. Why? How to resolve it?

Comment: Would you mind to be a bit quantitative and state how many nanoseconds [ns] the ideal process ought take ( start-to-end, incl. memory allocations ) for, say, a moderate size of 1.000.000 elements, not to call it slow ( or, very slow ) and what is the zone, where **in your context-of-use the process will be called fast**? That would be fair, wouldn't it?

Comment: In the first are you turning `ls_ws` into an array at the end, or leaving it as a list?

Comment: Are you measuring times for different values of `iterations`, or measuring the time for each iteration?

Comment: It's well-known that appending to a list involves malloc(), and in [tag:big-o] notation is O(n). Hence iteratively appending n items is O(n^2). Undesirably slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think here you have almost a good solution, but your treatment of columns vs. rows is probably hobbling the performance:

```
ls_ws=np.matrix(np.zeros((6,iterations))) 
for ind in range(iterations):
    ...
    ls_ws[:,ind]=ls_w
```

You should be iterating within the first dimension rather than the last.  You could swap the dimensions, or just do this:

```
ls_ws=np.matrix(np.zeros((6,iterations), order='F'))
```

That may help when the array is large, because you will be accessing contiguous chunks of 6 elements, rather than scattered bits in each iteration.

Comment: np.array, not np.matrix please

Comment: @ev-br what do you mean?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: You mention `compute_error()` in your comment here but not in your question!

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sorry, I got confused. This does seem to work. Can please explain what 'F' does?

Comment: Your memory is one-dimensional but can handle two-dimensional arrays. An array `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])` can be stored like `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` which is row major like in the language C (`order='C'`) or can be stored like `1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9` which is column major like in Fortran (`order='F'`). See e.g. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). Like in the answer mentioned, accessing consecutive positions in memory is faster.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: `order='F'` rearranges the data in memory to make your access pattern such that you operate on elements 0-5, then 6-11, then 12-17, vs originally you were operating on 0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, then 1, 1001, 2001, 3001, 4001, 5001, etc.  Doing it sequentially is faster for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: `numpy'` use of strides and memory copy is good enough that it is hard to find cases where iterating on the first dimension is measurably better than the last.

Comment: You could do the insertions column-wise, then transpose at the end.

Answer (score 1):

With a barebones version of the list append:

```
def foo1(N):
    alist = []
    for _ in range(N):
        alist.append([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    return np.array(alist)
```

times scale smoothly with N

```
In [4]: timeit foo1(100)
10000 loops, best of 3: 123 µs per loop
In [5]: timeit foo1(1000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop
In [6]: timeit foo1(10000)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop
In [7]: timeit foo1(100000)
10 loops, best of 3: 129 ms per loop
In [8]: timeit foo1(1000000)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.29 s per loop
In [9]: timeit foo1(10000000)
1 loop, best of 3: 12.9 s per loop
```

List append has the potential of slowing down with large lists.  A list uses a buffer to hold the pointers, plus some grow space.  When it outgrows that space it has to get more.  If it can't expand 'in-place' it will have to ask for new space and copy all pointers.  That can slow things down for very large lists that come close to filling memory.  I may be seeing hints of that with the move from 123 to 129 in the timings

```
def foo2(N):
    out = np.zeros((N,6),int)
    for i in range(N):
        out[i,:] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    return out
```

Times also scale with N and are double the list case:

```
In [15]: timeit foo2(100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 242 µs per loop
In [16]: timeit foo2(1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop
In [17]: timeit foo2(10000)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.6 ms per loop
In [18]: timeit foo2(100000)
1 loop, best of 3: 249 ms per loop
In [19]: timeit foo2(1000000)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.52 s per loop
In [20]: timeit foo2(10000000)
1 loop, best of 3: 25.2 s per loop
```

Iterating on the last dimension makes no difference in times

```
def foo3(N):
    out = np.zeros((6,N),int)
    for i in range(N):
        out[:,i] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    return out
```

Iterating 1000's of times while just assigning/creating 6 elements at a time is poor `numpy` practice.  If you must iterate it is better to loop a few times, while doing large operations each time.  eg 6 loops with 1000 item arrays.

If I move the iteration down to compiled code, times are much faster

```
def foo4(N):
    out = np.zeros((N,6),int)
    out[...] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    return out

In [28]: timeit foo4(1000)
.... cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.4 µs per loop
In [29]: timeit foo4(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 ms per loop
```

You talk about saving a matrix and even allocate a `np.matrix`.  So let's see what effect that has:

```
def foo1m(N):
    alist = []
    for _ in range(N):
        alist.append(np.matrix([1,2,3,4,5,6]).T)
    return np.concatenate(alist, axis=1)

def foo2m(N):
    out = np.matrix(np.zeros((6,N),int))
    for i in range(N):
        out[:,i] = np.matrix([1,2,3,4,5,6]).T
    return out

In [62]: timeit foo1(1000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop
In [63]: timeit foo1m(1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 18 ms per loop
In [64]: timeit foo2(1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.75 ms per loop
In [65]: timeit foo2m(1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.2 ms per loop
```

That makes the per/iteration times 10x longer.  `matrix` is a subclass of `ndarray`, and requires more processing (to force it to 2d etc).